# Passing an array as props, defining prop-types as array, but it says I'm passing an object

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying accessing an array of my reducer and mapping it as props.
It worked fine, but when I tried to standardize my code with ESLint, I needed to define my prop-types, and so I did it, as an array.

Then I receive an error saying: `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'articles_list' of type 'array' supplied to 'Content', expected 'object'`.

I search for it, and found people having trouble with the router, being advised to try the router beta... but it worked before ESLint.
I can't see what is wrong... I even doubt of my English understanding haha.. switching the prop-type to object, but anything worked.

In My Component

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  articles_list: state.articles_list,
});

class Content extends Component {
  ...
}

Content.propTypes = {
  articles_list: PropTypes.shape([]),
};
Content.defaultProps = {
  articles_list: [],
};
```

In My Reducer

```
const initialState = {
  articles_list: [],
}

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALL_ARTICLES_PAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        articles_list: [...state.articles_list, action.payload],
      };
      [...]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropTypes.shape` return  An `object` taking on a particular shape

try following:

```
 Content.propTypes = {
      articles_list: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape(*your object shape*)),
    };
```

if your array is array of number try :

```
   Content.propTypes = {
          articles_list: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
        };
```

Comment: Nice I didn't know the shape returns an object, it was really useful. I'll be aware of documentations in the next time haha. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
Content.propTypes = {
  articles_list: PropTypes.array,
};
```

Or you can use this if you want to define shape of array

```
Content.propTypes = {
  articles_list: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      code: PropTypes.string,
      id: PropTypes.number,
    })
  ),
};
```

Read documentation about all available propTypes [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

Comment: yep, I tried before this error, but as ESLint complains of generic prop-types, I used that way... But I tried now, I think it solved hahaha... the error gone, but there's a lot to fix yet haha.. 
But it helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcosDefina maybe remove this check from `eslintconfig` if you think it's not helpful to you